# Multiple integral graphs

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I've been going through two questions regarding multiple integrals:

Q1 - Find the centre of mass of a plate of constant density with shape
$$R = \{(x, y) \subset  \mathbb{R}^2: y\leq x^2, x\leq y^2\}.$$

For this question, I was quite confused by the identification of correct limits.

I took the same limits for both i.e. $1$ and $0$. The maximum that $y$ could be is $1$ to

satisfy the bounds and the lowest 0. The same applied for $x$.

Is this a reasonable approach?

Q2 - Write
$$ \iint_R f(x, y) \, dA$$
as a sum of double integrals in Cartesian coordinates where
$$R = \{(x, y) \subset \mathbb{R}^2: x^2 + y^2 \leq 2, x^2 + y^2 − 2x − 2y \leq  0\}$$
and $f$ is a continuous function on $R$.

I've drawn the two circles intersecting - with both radii equal to the square root of 2 — and have identified the limits.

I've decided to integrate the term: $$(-2x-2y) \, dy \, dx$$ which was obtained by taking the upper circle from the lower.

Am I taking the correct approach? To divide the integral into sums, I simply took the integral of the intersecting region to the left of the $y$-coordinate and to the right of the $y$-coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

As regards Q1, let $(\bar x, \bar y)$  the centre of mass, then
$$\bar x=\frac{1}{|R|}\int_{x=0}^1x\int_{y=x^2}^{\sqrt{y}}dy dx
\ ,\quad \bar y=\frac{1}{|R|}\int_{x=0}^1\int_{y=x^2}^{\sqrt{y}}y dy dx$$
where
$$|R|=\int_{x=0}^1\int_{y=x^2}^{\sqrt{y}} dy dx.$$
Note that by symmetry, $\bar x=\bar y$.

For Q2,  $x^2 + y^2 \leq 2$ is the disc centred at $(0,0)$ of radius $\sqrt{2}$ and , 
$x^2 + y^2 − 2x − 2y +2=(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2\leq  2$ is the disc centred at $(1,1)$ of radius $\sqrt{2}$. $R$ is the intersection of the two discs.

Note that $(1,1)$ is on the boundary of the first disc and $(0,0)$ is on the boundary of the second disc. Find $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ the intersections of the two circles with $x_1<x_2$, then it will be easy to write
$$\iint_R f(x, y) \, dA$$
as sum of double integrals in Cartesian coordinates